# Php fastCLI version 5.3.13 ignores include_path setting in ini.php

Tags: php, windows, iis-7, fastcgi

I am setting up `PHP` on `Windows Server 2008 SP1` (64 bit). I have configured `PHP` 5.3.13 which I managed to find over [here](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/). I have configured it in IIS to use fastCGI. As an aside, the reason that I used `PHP` 5.3.13 and not 5.4.3 is because I have not been able to find the 5.4 binary for the extension `php_win32service` which we need.

The issue that I am encountering though is that the `include_path` configured in the `php.ini` is being totally ignored by `PHP`. I have confirmed that I am changing the correct `php.ini` by making changes to other settings in the ini and I see these changes when I echo `phpinfo`. My `php.ini` is defined in the `C:\Windows` folder. But no matter what I put as the `include_path` in the ini file I always see ".;C:\php\pear" shown for the include path by `phpinfo`.

The include path that I have in my ini is copied/pasted from the ini on another server that is configured and working correctly. The only differences between the new server and the previous one is that the new one is 64 bit and the new one is running PHP 5.3.13 with fastCGI (as opposed to 5.2.1 with ISAPI for the one that is working).

So does anyone know whether the fact that `include_path` is being ignored is a bug in version 5.3.13 or if this behaviour is by design for `fastCGI`? Is there some setting that I could change in the `php.ini` that would resolve this?

Comment: I wouldn't trust the `php.ini` location like you are, try to modify the one in Program Files/`C:\php` too, if there is one. Are any other settings not being reflected?

Comment: I have deleted the `php.ini` from `c:\php`. The one in `c:\windows` is the only `php.ini` on the server. And I have confirmed that it is being used by changing `error_log` in the ini and I see the change I make reflected in `phpinfo`.

Comment: Please look in the phpinfo output and report what it says for Configuration File (php.ini) Path and Loaded Configuration File

Comment: @idipous He already has. @ Bruce This may seem like a stupid question, but since I've never come across this issue before, have you restarted IIS after making your changes?

Comment: @idipous Loaded Configuration File is `C:\Windows\php.ini`. @Rudi Visser Yes, I always restart IIS after making changes to the ini.

Comment: I am going to try replacing `PHP 5.3.13` with `PHP 5.4.3` and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Do you have read rights to the include path you are trying to add? It shouldn't make a difference but...

Comment: @idipous Yes, I do have read rights to the include path

Comment: Hmmmm. If I replace `PHP 5.3.13` with `PHP 5.4.3` and comment out the extension entry for `php_win32service` (because I don't have this binary) then it works correctly. It seems then that it is an issue with `PHP 5.3.13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the false conclusion I came to in the comments, because I must admit that this issue was in fact caused by an error in my `php.ini` file, so it was all my fault. ;) At some point during the editing of the `ini` file I accidentally put a carriage return character in the middle of one of the comment lines. This caused the processing of the `ini` to be cut off half way at the point that the error was encountered. I discovered this after installing 5.4.3, because this version actually reported an exception and showed a 500 Server Error message in the browser.

So what did I learn from this? Always test your `ini` file by doing `php -v` from the command line. If I had of done that I would have seen the message about the error encountered during the parsing of the `ini` file. Lesson learnt. :)